# Split array into fixed n chunks with dynamic sizes and all the combinations

Tags: javascript, split

I have an array say,

```
var a = [1,2,3];
```

which I want to split into exactly n number of chunks but having all the combinations in it.

Example:

when `n=2` it should return

```
combination1: [1],[2,3] or combination1: [2,3],[1]

combination2: [2],[1,3] or combination2: [1,3],[2]

combination3: [3],[1,2] or combination3: [1,2],[3]
```

I have tried this code but don't give me all combinations

```
function go(array, n) {
function iter(left, right) {
    var i,
        l = left.length - n + right.length + 1;

    if (right.length + 1 === n) {
        result.push(right.concat([left]));
        return;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
        iter(left.slice(i), right.concat([left.slice(0, i)]));
    }
}
var result = [];
iter(array, []);
return result;
```

}

Comment: OK. So, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried this code @ecg8

Comment: are you sure there is no duplicates ?

Comment: [1],[3,2] is duplicate to [2,3],[1]

Comment: No I want Only One case for [1],[3,2] or [2,3][1]
@Abra001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```js
Array.prototype.partition = function(i) {
  return this.reduce((a, r, l) => {
    if (typeof a === "number") return [ [[a, r]], [[a],[r]] ];
    V = [];
    a.forEach(u => {
      y = Array.from(u);
      if (i > y.length) {
        y.push([r]);
        V.push(y);
      }
      if (i - u.length <= this.length - l - 1) {
        u.forEach((t, t_i) => {
          t = t.concat(r);
          t = [t].concat(u.filter((z, z_i) => (z_i != t_i)));
          V.push(t);
        })
      }
    });
    return V;
  })
};
console.log([1, 2, 3].partition(2));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].partition(3));
```